# Python Intersection function doesn't work when lines share just one common endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, line, intersect

[image]

I have these  endpoints for function for line 1 (1,1) (4,1)  line 2 (4,1) (8,1).

Output is empty because **div** becomes 0 , how to handle this case in this function so that they are not treated as parallel lines and i get the endpoint as the intersection point?

My python function for intersection

```
  def line_intersection (line1, line2): 
        line1 = eval(str(line1))
        line2 = eval(str(line2))
        
        x1,x2,x3,x4  = float(line1[0][0]),float(line1[1][0]),float(line2[0][0]),float(line2[1][0])
        y1,y2,y3,y4  = float(line1[0][1]),float(line1[1][1]),float(line2[0][1]),float(line2[1][1])
        


        xdiff = (x1- x2,  x3 - x4)
        ydiff = (y1 - y2, y3 - y4)

        def det(a, b):
            i = a[0] * b[1] 
            j =  a[1] * b[0]
            return i - j

        div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
        if div == 0:
            # print("lines do not intersect")
            return 0

        d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
        x = det(d, xdiff) 
        x = x/ div
        y = det(d, ydiff) 
        y = y /div
        point = (x, y)
        

        x1, x2 = sorted([x1, x2])
        y1, y2 = sorted([y1, y2])
        if x < x1 or x > x2 or y < y1 or y > y2:
            # print("intersection point not within line segment")
            return 0

        x1, x2 = sorted([x1, x2])
        y1, y2 = sorted([y1, y2])
        if x < x1 or x > x2 or y < y1 or y > y2:
            # print("intersection point not within line segment")
            return 0

            return point

line1 = ((1, 1), (4, 1))
line2 = ((4, 1), (8, 1))
print(line_intersection(line1, line2))
```

Comment: It's important to figure out exactly what you want here. If the two lines share one endpoint (but not the other), then just return that point as the intersection, right? You can check for that inside the `if div == 0` block. (On the other hand, what if they overlap? Then, there are infinitely many points in the overlapping region that belong to both segments. What are you expecting to return in that case?)

Comment: the common endpoint i expect @StardustGogeta

Comment: in my case they wont overlap @StardustGogeta, as heading says only 1 common endpoint

Answer (score 0):

When div equals 0, the lines are considered to be parallel, and the function returns 0. If you want to handle the case where the lines are parallel and not return 0, you can add an if statement to check if div equals 0 and return a specific value or message indicating that the lines are parallel.

See if this helps:

```
def line_intersection(line1, line2): 
    line1 = eval(str(line1))
    line2 = eval(str(line2))

    x1,x2,x3,x4  = float(line1[0][0]),float(line1[1][0]),float(line2[0][0]),float(line2[1][0])
    y1,y2,y3,y4  = float(line1[0][1]),float(line1[1][1]),float(line2[0][1]),float(line2[1][1])

    # check if the lines are collinear
    if (y2 - y1) * (x4 - x3) == (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1):
        # check if they have a common endpoint
        if (x1, y1) == (x3, y3) or (x1, y1) == (x4, y4) or (x2, y2) == (x3, y3) or (x2, y2) == (x4, y4):
            # return the common endpoint
            return (x1, y1) if (x1, y1) == (x3, y3) or (x1, y1) == (x4, y4) else (x2, y2)
        else:
            return None

    xdiff = (x1- x2,  x3 - x4)
    ydiff = (y1 - y2, y3 - y4)

    def det(a, b):
        i = a[0] * b[1] 
        j =  a[1] * b[0]
        return i - j

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
        return None

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) 
    x = x/ div
    y = det(d, ydiff) 
    y = y /div
    point = (x, y)

    x1, x2 = sorted([x1, x2])
    y1, y2 = sorted([y1, y2])
    if x < x1 or x > x2 or y < y1 or y > y2:
        return None

    x1, x2 = sorted([x1, x2])
    y1, y2 = sorted([y1, y2])
    if x < x1 or x > x2 or y < y1 or y > y2:
        return None

    return point

line1 = ((1, 1), (4, 1))
line2 = ((4, 1), (8, 1))
print(line_intersection(line1, line2))
```

Let me know if I can give any further help

Comment: i want that common endpoint as intersection in that case @Tiago Vicente

Comment: see it now please

Comment: it is returning lines are parallel for 
line1 = ((1, 1), (4, 1))
line2 = ((4, 1), (8, 1))

Comment: just edited it again

Comment: it fails for case 
line1 = ((1, 0),(2, 0))
line2 = ((0, 0),(2, 0)) 

they are overlapping lines and it still considers them as intersection @Tiago Vicente